Helm chart .Files.Get inside range loop - Unknown object "nil"
I have an helm chart with array of objects in my values.yaml.
Each objects has:
Name,path,token.
So the array looks like:
my_array:
    - name: hi
      path: /some_path
      token: some_token

I want to iterate over that array as follows (creating a secret):
{{ - range .Values.my_array }}
    {{ .name }}-data: {{ $.Files.Get .path }}
    {{ .name }}-token: {{ .token }}
{{ end }}

Inside each {{ .name }}-data I want the actual content of the file in that path.
Doing it as above I get:
Unknown object "nil" 
Everything else works fine, if I change the file path to the actual path instead of .path it works OK.
What's the correct syntax?

Your code seems to be correct, maybe it's the path that needs to be fixed?
Consider the following folder structure:
/my-helmchart
  /files
    bar.txt
    foo.txt
  /templates
    sometemplate.yaml
  Chart.yaml
  values.yaml

Iterating over the array:
data:
  {{- range .Values.my_array }}
  {{ .name }}-data: {{ $.Files.Get .path }}
  {{ .name }}-token: {{ .token }}
  {{- end }}

Using the following values.yaml
my_array:
  - name: foo
    path: files/foo.txt
    token: foo_token
  - name: bar
    path: files/bar.txt
    token: bar_token

Output of helm template:
# Source: my-helmchart/templates/sometemplate.yaml
data:
  foo-data: This is the content of foo.txt
  foo-token: foo_token
  bar-data: This is the content of bar.txt
  bar-token: bar_token


The problem was indeed the path
